# Creating an image array and reading from it in matlab

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I wanted to create an array of images and for that i have used the following code:

```
 fileFolder = 'C:\Users\Shoiab\Desktop\New folder';
 >> filePattern = fullfile(fileFolder, '*.png');
 >> dirOutput = dir(filePattern);
 >> fileNames = {dirOutput.name}';
 >> numberOfImageFiles = numel(fileNames);

 >> myImage = imread(fileNames{1});
```

After executing the above code, i am not able to read the images from array and getting the following error:

??? Error using ==> imread at 363
File "001L_1.png" does not exist.

But the Image file is present at the set directory, so kindly help me in resolving this:

Comment: Try to call imread with complete path imread(fullfile(fileFolder, fileNames{1})). By default imread try to search files in script folder.

Comment: it is still showing me the same error. Can you elaborate it further

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that when you use the `imread` function the folder that contains the image is in the MATLAB's path?

You can use something like:

```
prevDir = cd(fileFolder); % change directory to the folder containing the image
```

immediatly before using the `imread` function.

The variable `prevDir` contains the path of the directory where you were before.

Hope this helps.